# Use custom UISearchBar with UISearchController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to use a custom UISearchBar with the UISearchController as navigation title to work around the issue with iOS 11 that the height changed from 44 to 56 points. But I fail to understand how I can set the custom search bar to the search controller - the searchbar property is read-only. All my searches on the topic didn't result in anthing that helps me get on the right path.

Here is my search controller code:

*Note: AppSearchControllerViewController is a simple UITableViewController displaying the results via an NSMutableArray*

*Note 2: the view controller implements the delegate "UISearchBarDelegate"*

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    searchResultsController = [[AppSearchControllerViewController alloc] init];
    appSearchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    [searchResultsController setParentNavigationController:self.navigationController];
    appSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    appSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
    // Usually one would set up the searchbar like this
    //  self.navigationItem.titleView = appSearchController.searchBar;
    // but instead I do this:
    [self addSearchBar];
}

- (void)addSearchBar {
    _searchBar = [self addSearchBarWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth - 2 * 44 - 2 * 15, 44)];
    UIView *wrapView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_searchBar.frame];
    [wrapView addSubview:_searchBar];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = wrapView;
}

- (WMSearchBar *)addSearchBarWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    WMSearchBar *searchBar = [[WMSearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchBar.placeholder = [Language get:@"APP_SEARCH_NAVBAR_TEXTFIELD_SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER"];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO];
    [searchBar setTintColor:KGenericColor];

    if (self.isChangeSearchBarFrame) {
        CGFloat height = searchBar.bounds.size.height;
        CGFloat top = (height - 20.0) / 2.0;
        CGFloat bottom = top;
        searchBar.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, 0, bottom, 0);
    }
    return searchBar;
}
```

WMSearchBar class is from this Github repo: https://github.com/DreamTravelingLight/searchBarDemo

This make the search bar perfectly fit again to 44 points and also do the fade in/out animation on controller transitions.

The issue is now, that I receive all the events from the search bar - that all works. But the search results controller is not triggered so the results also don't display.

I tried also to set the original search bar's text from my custom new search bar, but same effect - results controller does not show up. What do I need to do to wire in the new search bar and replace the old one?

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"textDidChange: %@", searchText);
    appSearchController.searchBar.text = searchText;
    ...
```

Comment: Why do not use search bar only?

Comment: Because I need to display the search results in a table view controller right away.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261248/how-to-impliment-search-bar-in-table-view-for-contacts-in-ios/38264318#38264318

Comment: That is not the issue I have, it's more the setup of the search controller with this custom search bar and how I can get the delegates wired up correctly. The results container itself is working that I have, totally fine. Just the Search results is not firing up.

Comment: I think the issue is that usually you return your custom UISearchBar. In this special case, the search bar is wrapped into an UIView to match the size of the title view in the nav bar. Without the wrapper, the size of the bar jumps again to 56.